# aws s3-sync feature in c# (for mobile applications - Android and iOS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-s3

I have used aws-s3 sync feature from linux and windows machines (aws cli). I have a similar requirement for the mobile applications (Android and iOS) too. The mobile apps are built on Xamarin (C#).

Is there a way, I can do s3-sync from mobile applications using API or any other way?

Also if there is no way to do the same, is there any other way apart from s3-sync to sync a s3-bucket in server to a local folder in mobile app?

Comment: AWS has full C# libraries that support .NETStd 1.3+ (and older ones that support Xamarin PCLs) so yes you can use the SDK to obtain the contents of a bucket, compare that to your local app cache and download the new/changed items....

Comment: @SushiHangover, Thanks for the response.
But rather I am looking for something similar to `aws s3 --sync` command line command where I no need to take care of comparing the names, deletions, versions etc.,

Comment: The AWS cli is open source, you could always reimplement the python code, but to be honest, I did an exacttimestamp sync (like the `sync --exact-timestamps` for Android and iOS in about 30 lines of C# code...)

Comment: @SushiHangover, Thanks. Could you help me further with the same.